# Reading data from DS4 Controller for school project - keep receiving hid_open error

Tags: c, linux, cygwin

I am doing a school project where we have to read in data from a PS4 controller by running a school provided `DS4rd.exe` in cygwin.

I am trying to get it set up on my personal computer, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work.

I am running the command:

```
./ds4rd.exe
```

which does device enumeration and lists the PS4 controller and the VID/PID.

I am then running the `./ds4rd.exe` command with the given arguments to read data off the controller but I keep receiving:

> hid_open, try device enumeration and check vendor id and product id values

I am not familiar with how these packages really work. Does anyone have an idea of what could be giving me this error?

[image: Console Output]

Comment: 1) your `DS4rd.exe` may have more options that allows it to open a device that is already open by another app, or 2) You are running something that your exe does not expect to be running, perhaps a game or a controller test or setup app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the cygwin folder from the schools computer and transfer it to yours. Your cygwin folder should be replaced with theirs.